# libGL.so cause Failing to start android emulator on archlinux by normal user, but worked by root user

Tags: android, archlinux

libGL.so cause Failing to start android emulator on archlinux by normal user, but worked by root user.

Please refer to following log:

```
xx@vm-arch:/opt/android-sdk/tools$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose emulator-arm -avd xtest

libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: XF86DRIGetClientDriverName: 1.0.0 vboxvideo (screen 0)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/tls/vboxvideo_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/vboxvideo_dri.so
drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
drmOpenDevice: open result is 10, (OK)
drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:02.0
drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
drmOpenDevice: open result is 10, (OK)
drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 10
drmOpenByBusid: Interface 1.4 failed, trying 1.1
drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:02.0
libGL error: Calling driver entry point failedlibGL error: reverting to software direct rendering
libGL error: failed to load driver: 
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/xorg/modules/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/qt/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/qt/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/qt/.drirc: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by checked "3D acceleration" in Virtualbox options.

After unchecked that option, the issue is gone.

Thanks for your attention.